# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar una variable de MySql de tipo date?

Tags: python, variables

Estoy intentando crear en una tabla de pydantic una variable de tipo date que esta en mi base de datos, pero me dice que date no es un tipo de variables, como puedo almacenarla.

```
class Solicitud(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[int]
    nombre: str
    password: str
    mail: str
    tokenPrimario: str
    fechaSolicitud: date    <--- Aqui esta el problema
    nombreAvatar: str
    sexoAvatar: str
```

Comment: fechaSolicitud: date  no lo puedo poner como (str) pero que variable tiene python para almacer un tipo date de MySql

Comment: buscar en internet no sirvio?? ;) https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: ya busque ahi antes y no estaba lo que necesito.

Comment: bien mira lo de antes lo resolvi, agregando datetime

Comment: pero no aun asi eso no resolvio lo de los modelos:                 table_solicitud_Model = Table("solicitudes", meta,                                  Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),                                             Column("fechaSolicitud", date), )    <-- este tipo de datos no me lo acepta.

Comment: sabes que hay un boton [edit] que te permite agregar toda tu info en la pregunta, no? de paso, parece que tu pregunta es sobre ese componente y sus variables, no sobre python y sus variables... es muyyyyyyy diferente el problema a lo que planteaste arriba...

Comment: Sorry soy nuevo aqui y no entiendo muy bien ;) pues si el problema es que al intentar crear la tabla en python me dice que la variable date no es una variable correcta, y lo que necesito es que la taba en python me acepte que no es un tipo :string como las demas sino un tipo :date, pero no se como decirselo. los tipos de variables que conozco son string, integer, bool, float. pero no conozco una variable para decirla a python ( date ), en el esquema si me lo acepta pero en la tabla no.